# XCode 9.1 crashes, just after running app on device or simulator

Tags: swift, xcode, macos-sierra

XCode 9.2 started crashing just after I run my app, either on simulator or real device.
Is there any reset or reinstall for XCode?

I am using these PODs:

```
  # Pods for Handee Client
  pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'PMSuperButton'
  pod 'RAMAnimatedTabBarController', '~> 3.0.1'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'PopupDialog', '~> 0.6'
  pod 'Font-Awesome-Swift', '~> 1.7.1'
  pod 'IGZLocation', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'SMDatePicker'
  pod 'ALCameraViewController', '~> 2.0.3'
  pod 'XLPagerTabStrip', '~> 8.0'
  pod 'HCSStarRatingView', '~> 1.5'
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.5'
  pod 'AlamofireObjectMapper', '~> 5.0'
  pod 'AlamofireImage', '~> 3.3'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 3.0.1'
  pod 'DGElasticPullToRefresh'
  pod 'RxSwift',    '~> 4.0'
  pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 4.0'
  pod 'PKHUD', '~> 5.0'
```

Comment: What libraries do you use? Maybe Realm?

Comment: @SergeyGamayunov check pods above, please.

Comment: Sometimes reinstalling app may help...

Comment: going to update XCode to 9.2, will tell you the result.

Comment: nope, same problem, XCode 9.2 crashes too.

Comment: It was RxSwift! But why it can crash and quit XCode?

Comment: I faced the same problem when I updated Realm. Xcode is just weird:)